# How to fix name of github Action

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

[GITHUB ACTION PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PBIU.png)

As you see in this picture, I have two same workflow .
I would like to fix the name of one workflow from robo-advisor-dev to robo-advisor-prod
But it seems it can not be changed once registered
Is there any way I can fix the name of workflow??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you have a screenshot to share, it is better to embed it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably used the **same name** for *both workflows*. Something like this:

```
name: robo-advisor-dev
on: [push]
jobs:
    [...]
```

To correct it, you need to update one of the workflow name and push the update to the **default** branch.

```
name: robo-advisor-prod
on: [push]
jobs:
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `name` property for workflows, jobs and steps.

From the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions):

- [`name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#name)
- [`jobs.<job_id>.name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idname)
- [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsname)